# Stickers or swag request for Bicycles SE promotional purposes

Tags: support, site-promotion

A local cafe that I frequent (likely too often) has a real cycling theme with many cyclists dropping by...

Can I request some stickers or other self promotion stuff that I could give to them to put in their for people to grab? Happy to pay a few bucks for postage to Australia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can request swag items -- including site-specific ones! -- to hand out as an individual [right here](http://s.tk/swagrequest).

If we (that is, Stack Exchange) sponsors you for a conference, swag is usually included.

Cheers, and thanks for wanting to spread the word about the site; users like you help a community grow. :)